# Get Raspi's CPU temperature within Docker container

Tags: raspberry-pi, docker, container

I've build a little ASP.NET Core application for my Raspberry Pi 4 which lets me control a fan ([see here](https://github.com/mu88/RaspiFanController/)). The app is deployed as a small self-contained Linux application running on bare metal of my Raspi.

For measuring the temperature, I'm calling `vcgencmd measure_temp` on the Raspi which gives me the actual temperature.

For various reasons, I'd prefer to run this app within a Docker container:

- No more manual service registration within Linux, Docker feature `--restart-always` handles this.
- No more downloading the latest release from GitHub, extracting and marking the app as executable.

But I have no clue how I can retrieve the Raspi's temperature from within a container.

I already tried to map the Raspi's directory `/usr/bin/` and `/opt/vc/bin/` into a Docker container and call `vcgencmd` from inside - but that simply fails due to missing dependencies.
And I already found an answer on Stack Overflow suggesting to create a named pipe on the Raspi and then consume this pipe from within the container. But this removes the beauty of a container if I have to setup something like a named pipe.

So long story short: is there any way to get the Raspi's current CPU temperature from within a Docker container?

Thx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we just mount `/opt/vc` inside a container...

```
docker run -it --rm -v /opt/vc:/opt/vc debian:stretch /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
```

...it fails with:

```
/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd: error while loading shared libraries: libvchiq_arm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Where do we find `libvchiq_arm.so`? We can use `ldd` to find out:

```
$ ldd /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7efe7000)
        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so (0x76f79000)
        libvchiq_arm.so => /opt/vc/lib/libvchiq_arm.so (0x76f52000)
        libvcos.so => /opt/vc/lib/libvcos.so (0x76f39000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0x76f0f000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0x76efc000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1 (0x76ee5000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x76d97000)
        /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76f8e000)
```

This shows us that `vcgencmd` wants two libraries that can be found in `/opt/vc/lib`. These are *available* in the container, but the container environment doesn't know to look for them in `/opt/vc/lib`. We can fix that by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /opt/vc:/opt/vc -e LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/vc/lib debian:stretch /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
```

Which fails with:

```
VCHI initialization failed
```

Great, we've solved the missing library problem! I suspect that `vcgencmd` is looking for a device that isn't available in the container. We can figure out what that is by running `vcgencmd` on the host under the control of `strace`:

```
strace -o /tmp/trace  -f -s 80 /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
```

Now we look for `/dev` in `/tmp/trace`, and we find:

```
6868  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/vchiq", O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
```

So we need to expose `/dev/vchiq` inside the container. We can do that with the `--device` option:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /opt:/opt -e LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/vc/lib --device /dev/vchiq debian:stretch /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
```

Which now reports:

```
temp=69.3'C
```

We have successfully run `vcgencmd` inside a container.

Comment: WOW! If possible, I'd give you two upvotes for this answer. Super explanation, I learned so much. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by @larsks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/706181/377345), is great. However, now in the RaspberryPI 4 with `Debian 11 (bulleye) aarch64`, they have placed `vcgencmd` from `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd` to `/usr/bin/vcgencmd`. In consequence, here is the updated version of [mu88](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/529445/mu88) solution:

```shell
docker run -it --rm -v /usr:/usr -e LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib --device /dev/vchiq debian:stretch /usr/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
```